# defmethod dispatch when varargs involved

Tags: clojure

I am trying to find a way to define a multi-method that (a) dispatches on multiple args and (b) allows methods to be specified that care only about some of the args (the compiler does not like the _ in the last method):

```
(defmulti whocares (fn [a1 a2] [(class a1)(class a2)]))

(defmethod whocares [String String] [s1 s2]
  (println :s2 s1 s2))

(defmethod whocares [_ String] [any1 s2]
  (println :_s any1 s2))
```

Compiler definitely does not like that _.

I know about the :default catch-all, but I need something more granular (on individual args).

In CL we would use t as the type that matches everything, but I do not see indication clojure has something for X such that (isa? whatever X) would always return true.

btw, I imagine there is a top to the Java class hierarchy, but I am trying to stay away from my library supporting only Java classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `java.lang.Object` as your catch all type:

```
(defmulti whocares (fn [a b] [(class a) (class b)]))

(defmethod whocares [String String] [a b] (println "Two strings" a b))

(defmethod whocares [Object String] [a b] (println "Anything and string" a b))

(whocares "a" "b")
;; => "Two strings a b"

(whocares 1 "c")
;; => "Anything and string 1 c"

(whocares :a "c")
;; => "Anything and string :a c"
```

I am not sure why you don't want to use the top class of Java hierarchy. It's possible using `derive` to define your catch all dispatch value but you still need to make the Java's `Object` class a child of your custom catch all value:

```
(derive Object :whocares/any)

(defmulti whocares2 (fn [a b] [(class a) (class b)]))

(defmethod whocares2 [String String] [a b] (println "Two strings" a b))

(defmethod whocares2 [:whocares/any String] [a b] (println "Anything and string" a b))

(whocares2 "a" "b")
;; => "Two strings a b"

(whocares2 1 "c")
;; => "Anything and string 1 c"

(whocares2 :a "c")
;; => "Anything and string :a c"
```

Comment: Thx, I'm an idiot. :) I tried everything except Object, assuming (oops) it would not match integers.